# Three.js FBXLoader2, change color of single Mesh (in Group or detached)

Tags: three.js

I have a .fbx model which load via FBXLoader2.
When I add the model (which include 3 meshes) to the scene, it is added as a Group. Now I try to change the color of a single Mesh in the Group, but all 3 meshes are getting the color. Then i thought they might be "linked" because of the Group. So i detached them (SceneUtils.detach).
Now I have all the meshes in the scene. Still, when I change the color of a single mesh, all three of them get the color. When I console.log the mesh (in the group or detached) it shows me the correct mesh.

```
var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader( manager ); 

loader.load( 'somemodel.fbx', function( object ) {

  model = object;
  var modelLength = model.children.length;

  for (i=0;i<modelLength;i++) {
    THREE.SceneUtils.detach(model.children[0], model, scene);
  }
  scene.children[0].material.emissive.setHex( 0xff0000 );
}
```

When i try to change position or scale the mesh, it works fine. 
Anybody had the problem before?

Comment: This is because they are sharing the same Material instance, so when you change the color of this instance all your meshes are affected by the change.
Try to create a new Material instance with the new color for the mesh that you want to update instead of changing the color

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks, i will check this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clone the material and replace it with original once.

```
scene.children[0].material = scene.children[0].material.clone();
scene.children[0].material.emissive.setHex( 0xff0000 );
```